# Command line modification using Smultron instead of Textmate for mate commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through the railstutorial.org Chapter 3 tutorial and the instructor asked us to create a new html file with the command:

$ mate public/hello.html

However, I'm not using Textmate in this case, but rather Smultron as my text editor. That said, I receive the error message:

-bash: mate: command not found

Do you know what word I should replace "mate" with to properly communicate with Smultron?

Answer (score 0):

When Textmate is installed, it puts a `mate` executable in `/usr/local/bin/`.  If you're not using Textmate, you won't have that command.

Older versions of Smultron placed a `smultron` executable in the path.  I don't imagine that's changed, but I don't have the lastest version of Smultron to confirm that.  I also don't remember if you have to provide any kind of command line switches when creating a new file.

**Edit:** To get command-line support in Smultron 4, download this: http://www.peterborgapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/smultron-commandlineutility4.zip

Comment: It looks like the latest version of Smultron does not provide a command-line executable.  Just run Smultron, create a new file, and save it in the **public** folder of your app with the name **hello.html**.  All `mate public/hello.html` does is open an empty file in Textmate that will be called **hello.html** and saved to **public** when you save it.

Comment: Cool. Yeah that's what I've been doing, but just thought there might be an easier way in the terminal.

Comment: Just came across this: http://sometimesitmatters.com/post/7924140943/smultron-4-command-line-utility-now-available